# Get last URI segment excluding query string

Tags: php

I have an URL say: `www.abc.com/blog/2012/12/register-car?w=Search&searchDmv=Go`. I want to extract the string `register-car` from it using php code. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php 

 $url = "www.abc.com/blog/2012/12/register-car?w=Search&searchDmv=Go";

 $register_car = basename(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));

 echo $register_car; // will echo "register-car"

?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me how can i get 2012 as output from the same code.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) function, followed by basename to return the last /item/. The following prints `register-car`.

```
  $parsed = parse_url("http://www.abc.com/blog/2012/12/register-car?w=Search&searchDmv=Go", PHP_URL_HOST);
  echo basename($parsed['path']);
```

Comment: Well, that's not entirely accurate. It may work in this particular situation, but one would be wise to note that parse_url does not guarantee it can parse partial URLs. So for example if I wanted the host name from this URL without including the scheme I would get the wrong result. `var_dump(parse_url("www.abc.com/blog/2012/12/register-car?w=Search&searchDmv=Go", PHP_URL_HOST));` gives you `NULL`

Comment: Woops, yeah, the previous comment is ambiguous. Don't expect it to work without using a full URL. I take it example #2 on parse_url's page is by you ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of [parse_url](http://php.net/parse-url) and [basename](http://php.net/basename), or even [pathinfo](http://php.net/pathinfo) to help you with this.

In PHP < 5.4.7

```
$url = "www.abc.com/blog/2012/12/register-car?w=Search&searchDmv=Go";
$result = basename(parse_url("http://" . $url, PHP_URL_PATH));
echo $result; // register-car
```

In PHP >= 5.4.7

```
$url = "www.abc.com/blog/2012/12/register-car?w=Search&searchDmv=Go";
$result = basename(parse_url("//" . $url, PHP_URL_PATH));
echo $result; // register-car
```

Comment: Warning: parse_url() has been disabled for security reasons
Can you help me with this

Comment: It sounds like your sysadmin has added this function to [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) in php.ini, which just sounds weird because this function poses virtually no security risks I can think of. You will need to contact whoever is responsible for your PHP installation and ask them if they can remove this function from the disable_functions directive in php.ini.

Answer (score -1):

```
$parts = parse_url("www.abc.com/blog/2012/12/register-car?w=Search&searchDmv=Go", PHP_URL_PATH);
$pieces = explode($parts, "/");
$action = $pieces[count($pieces)-1];
```

Comment: You should test your code. The [explode](http://php.net/explode) function does not accept the delimiter as the second argument. Additionally, that code will prove very buggy since it does not take into account that the URL may contain a fragment.

Comment: You're right.. Guess that what happens when I answer questions quickly with no sleep..

Comment: It happens to the best of us. I just figured maybe you could edit it to reflect correct behavior since it's still fresh :)

Comment: nah, that's fine.. I'd rather not be like the guy above you that gives a gives a rushed answer then then corrects it 2 or three times after you have given a much more eloquent answer and then gets their answer chosen as correct ;) - cheers

Comment: At least you're honest. That's an admirable quality :)